# javascript - Foreach JSON with random keys

Tags: javascript, json

I currently experience the problem when i want to deserialize json. I dont know how to do this with unknown keys

```
[
    {
        "84.200.222.4": [
            0.022
        ]
    },
    {
        "84.200.230.82": [
            1.315
        ]
    },
    {
        "80.156.160.161": [
            0.874
        ]
    },
    {
        "72.14.217.108": [
            0.662
        ]
    },
    {
        "108.170.251.193": [
            0.638
        ]
    },
    {
        "216.239.54.61": [
            0.64
        ]
    },
    {
        "172.217.23.131": [
            0.564
        ]
    }
]
```

How would i go about this when i want

```
1. 84.200.222.4
- 0.022

2. 84.200.230.82
- 1,315

3. 80.156.160.161
- 0.874

4 72.14.217.108
- 0.662
```

Etc.. I'm currently not sure on how to loop through unknown keys is that possible?

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(obj).forEach((k, i) => console.log(\`${i}. ${key} \n ${obj[key]}\`)`

Comment: IP addresses and weights...?

Answer (score 5):

Simply iterate through the array, and use `Object.keys()`, which returns an array of all the object's properties.

```
arr.forEach(obj => {
    console.log(Object.keys(obj)[0]);
})
```

Comment: This works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't test this but It should work.

Firstly it's an array so you want to loop over that. Then although the object keys vary, you can use object.keys to get the keys of an object, or just iterate over the object. So your code would look like so

```
function printValues(arr)
{
    var arrayLength = arr.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) 
    {
        let obj = arr[i];
        for (var key in obj) {
            x = obj[key];
            alert(x);
        }
    }
}
```

This could be optimized down to a single line but I made it as simple as possible for you to understand.

Comment: use `forEach` to loop over arrays

Comment: @randnum-1 that's not a requirement. For loops are just as valid.

Comment: @randnum-1 I admit forEach are the best thing to use but based on OP's question I don't think he has a firm grasp on the basics yet so I didn't want to shrink the code.

Comment: Actually can do things with a `for()` you can't with `forEach` like `break`...not that it's applicable in OP case but nothing wrong with using `for()`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick way to process it:

```js
var array = [{
  "84.200.222.4": [0.022]
}, {
  "84.200.230.82": [1.315]
}, {
  "80.156.160.161": [0.874]
}, {
  "72.14.217.108": [0.662]
}, {
  "108.170.251.193": [0.638]
}, {
  "216.239.54.61": [0.64]
}, {
  "172.217.23.131": [0.564]
}];

array.forEach((object, index) => {
  var ip = Object.keys(object).pop();
  console.log(`${index + 1}. ${ip}\n- ${object[ip]}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
```

this will return a javascript object/array.

then do

```
var result = parsed[0].keys.map(key => { /** do whatever **/});
```